# Closure with for loop

Tags: javascript

Here is the code with works perfectly, what is `(i)` after curly bracket

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(j) { 
    console.log(j);
  }(i), 1000);
}
```

Is this the way to pass the parameter value in an anonymous function?

Comment: It calls the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take this case:

```
  function fn(j) { // function declaration
    console.log(j);
  }

  fn(j); // function call
```

That calls the function. Now as functions can also be expressions, they can evaluate to a reference, and one can call that function by adding `()` after the reference, just as above. That means that

```
  function(j){ /*..*/ }(i)
```

actually calls the function directly without waiting.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `setTimeout` is a function expression which accepts one argument. `i` supplies the value to that argument, and `(i)` calls the function expression with the value of `i`.

The reason is because you cannot use `i` directly inside the callback of `setTimeout` as that will produce unwanted behaviour due to the asynchronous nature of `setTimeout` and synchronous nature of `for` loop.

Handling this situation with a function expression ensures that the value of `i` is bound to `j`, which correctly produces the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

> That creates the immediately executing function expression () through which the JavaScript engine will directly interpret the function.